# jQuery functions not working after JS innerHTML property

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml, craftyjs

I am using this code in my application:

```
document.getElementById("inventory_box").innerHTML = "<img src='./img/rock.gif' id='test' />";
```

The `#inventory_box` element is present already, so it just spews out the `IMG` into `#inventory_box`.

What I want is to be able to click this appeared `IMG` with id name `test`,
but won't work like:

```
$("#test").click(function() {
                // Run this
            });
```

Comment: try on instead  if ur using latest version of jquery..

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
$(document).on('click',"#test",function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

Read [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on)

Answer (score 1):

Since the image is added dynamically, you need to use [`event delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handler

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$('#inventory_box').on('click', '#test', function() {
      // Run this
});
```

This will attach your event to `test` image element within the `#inventory_box` element, 
reducing the scope of having to check the whole `document` element tree and increasing efficiency.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not seem to be working. The one by Rohan seems to work for me...will using the one by Rohan slow performance down?

Comment: Yes, incase you don't have a nearest parent selector (already present in the DOM), you will have to use the `document` element. Only thing being, the code will check the whole document element tree for the new image being added, which takes some time!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using 'append' instead of innerHTML. Using a mix of vanilla JavaScript & jQuery seems to be causing some delay in updating the DOM with the new element.
The code below works for me.

```
$("#inventory_box").append("<img src='./img/rock.gif' id='test' />")

$('#test').click(function(d){console.log("clicked!");});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment of event handler runs before there is an element having such id, so after you create an element, it will not have any event handler assigned to it.

As it was suggested, easiest way to solve this common javascript error, you can assign event to a container DOM element and use jquery's event delegation to fire events on event newly added DOM elements.

But I rather not use this approach, the reason I can not give you, say, I just simply prefer not to.

Always assign events after element is created. for example:

```
document.getElementById("inventory_box").innerHTML = "<img src='./img/rock.gif' id='test' />";
```

immediately after this, execute this:

```
$("#test").click(function() {
                // Run this
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#inventory_box img').click(function() {
      // Run this
});
```