# window.addEventListener conflicting with jQuery event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I have this simple scenario where I am first binding javascript event listeners like so:

```
(function () {

/*Loading widget initialization code on window load*/
if (window.addEventListener) {// W3C standard
    window.addEventListener('load', initWidget, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {// Microsoft
    window.attachEvent('onload', initWidget);
}

})();
```

Please don't mind the `initWidget` as it is defined and works I just didn't put the code here since it was not needed.

So these events work fine, but when I add some jquery event handlers in there, the jquery events don't work. I add the jQuery events in `$.ready()` like so :

```
$().ready(function() {
$("#header").mouseover(function() {
    $("#header").css("background-color", "red");
}).mouseout(function() {
    $("#header").css("background-color", "transparent");
});
})
```

The jQuery `mouseover` and `mouseout` don't work unless I remove the `window.addEventListener` code block. Somehow js events are causing conflicts with jQuery and there is nothing in console.

I have also put up a fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/kzmvaysq/ replicating the exact problem. I need a way so that event listeners don't conflict with jQuery.

**UPDATE**

I traced to the main problem area and that seems to be trying to change the innerHTML of `body` tag in `initWidget`. If you see the fiddle now : https://jsfiddle.net/kzmvaysq/4/ it might help you better understand the problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7wj2zk4L/1/ - fiddle is fine

Comment: @ArunPJohny Please see update to the post.

Comment: jQuery's event model requires it to add properties to DOM elements (which is one reason that some will not use it). Using `+=` with the *innerHTML* property probably requires the entire document body to be serialised then reparsed, trashing jQuery's DOM properties (and listeners added by *addEventListener*).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML += mainButtons;` which replaces the current dom structure with a new one, which will result in loosing all the events/data attached to each element by jQuery.

A simple solution is to append a new div element, instead of using innerHTML to add the new content

```
function initWidget() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = 'Somehtml';
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(div);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7wj2zk4L/)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot actually name a reason of it.
However, I would recommend you switching all of your events to jQuery to prevent conflicts.

You can attach the same event this way:

```
 $(window).load(initWidget);
```

It will also decrease the amount of code because jQuery applies events correctly for you.

Here is the [JS Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kzmvaysq/2/) based on your one.

**Update:** Why do you think that it conflicts at all?

Here is an [another JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kzmvaysq/3/) and it's working for me.

**Update 2:**

It is a known problem. If you change JS element properties and use jQuery events, it causes some problems. 
Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224085/jquery-functions-not-working-after-js-innerhtml-property).

You need to choose one of this options:

1. Assign events AFTER you have changed your `innerHTML`. Now it happens before it because `$(document).ready()` is being fired before `$(window).load()`.

For example, place your `#header` events to `initWidget` after editing.

2. Use **`jQuery.append()`** function (as for me, that is the best solution).

For example, this way:

```
function initWidget() 
{
    $("body").append("<div>Somehtml</div>");
}
```

3. Use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Look at this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('mouseover', '#header', function() {
        $("#header").css("background-color", "red");
    });
    $(document).on('mouseout', '#header', function() {
        $("#header").css("background-color", "transparent");
    });
});

Here is the [JS Fiddle Demo][5].
```

Comment: I don't want to use jquery at all in the widget code

Comment: I just want it so that it does not conflict with host page scripts.

Comment: @hussain Ok. Take a look again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any conflict.

When I added `initWidget()` function it started working.

Here is the fiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/51sxLe7f/

Updated fiddle  - https://jsfiddle.net/pg40wp43/2/

Comment: Use jQuery.append instead of  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML += mainButtons;   - $('body').append(mainButtons);

Comment: Well, i cannot use jQuery, that's the problem.